# Bootstrap - active link in the menu in Chrome and collapsed menu on mobile not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've made WP theme based on Twitter Bootstrap theme, but

1) I've lost somewhere functionality of active link in the menu in Google Chrome (don't know, what has happened - in Firefox it is working fine).

and second problem is probably related:

2) in mobile resolution (i.e. small screens) there is collapsed menu, after choosing one of items in the menu it should collapse itself again, but it's not working.

[SITE IS HERE](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/vrananska)

Could anybody try to help me solve the problems? I've asked in WPMUDEV but nobody has answered. Code all the stuff is already there: http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/problem-with-bootstrap-menu-active-link-on-one-page-theme#post-785738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For closing the dropdown menu use:

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
    $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

This is wired to the document, so you don't have to do it on ready().